# Is there a function to count occurences of a value in a range with Excel 2007?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a column in a sheet of my workbook which contains "OK" or "NOK".

Which formula can I use to compute the number of cells which contains "OK" in the range ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your range is `A1:A5`:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"OK")
```

Or for the whole column:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"OK")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as i can. However, please not than in Excel 2007, parameters separator is ; and not , in function calls

Comment: @user1060205 The separator depends on your locale, not on the version of Excel. If you are in France for example, it is `;`, but in the UK it is `,`...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `CountIf()` Worksheet Function. It sounds as if this will do exactly what you need.